# $ref in response example

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

The response example I would like to put in the yaml file is something like:

`{
    "name": "Element",
    "schema": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "extension": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/Extension"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`

And the ymal of this example will be:

```
responses:
    200:
      description: "successful operation, return the definition of the resource type in the body"
      examples:
        application/json:
          name: Element
          schema:
            properties:
              id:
                type: string
              extension:
                type: array
                items: 
                  $ref: '#/definitions/Extension'
```

As you can see the last line is "$ref: '#/definitions/Extension'", thus Swagger thinks it is a reference which it can not find anywhere in the ymal file.

Is it possible to escape this to get way from being a reference?

Answer (score 0):

This is [a bug](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4765) in Swagger Editor and UI.

As a workaround, define a `schema` for your response and use a schema example instead. Schema examples are displayed fine in Swagger Editor 3.6.6 and Swagger UI 3.17.5. You might still see a $ref resolution error in the editor, but at least the example is displayed correctly.

```yaml
      responses:
        200:
          description: "successful operation, return the definition of the resource type in the body"
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/MyResponseSchema'

definitions:
  MyResponseSchema:
    type: object
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          ...
    example:    # <------------
      name: Element
      schema:
        properties:
          id:
            type: string
          extension:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/Extension'
```